# Improve pronunciation if one's English level is already ~C1?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I've been studying English for a while and considered myself a good speaker (mostly because I had passed CAE a year ago). Lately, though, I found myself in an environment where English is used a lot and I realized my pronunciation is far from perfect. What are some ways for me to improve it? Is it not too late? Unfortunately, living in England is not an option.

I really hope not all is lost for me!

Comment: [This question is kind of off-topic, but allow me to give you some advice. There are articles devoted to "typical" accents by a speaker of one language speaking another. Spanish, Chinese or German speakers will have different issues in pronouncing English words. Find yours and work on those points first.]

Comment: @Lambie Thank you! This is a solid advice, however even though I'm Russian I watched a lot of content in American English, I think I have quite a weird mix of problems now. I'll try to identify the specific problems, as you advised! P.S. What would be the appropriate section for my question?

Comment: You don't have to have perfect pronunciation, and **if you're communicating with the same people in English** (or whatever language) **on a daily basis**, you're invariably going to learn their accent, and they'll learn yours, meaning you'll understand each other ~perfectly. Ever watched those Youtube videos where the guy isn't a native speaker of English, and yet after the initial hurdle you somehow get everything they're trying to say? Sometimes a "perfect" accent can actually hinder communication. If I were you, I wouldn't waste my time on trying to improve pronunciation.

Comment: @Max  Go find some Russian interpreting site. Interpreters are the ones who know this problem well. Some people's accents need help; others are just charming. If you accent is very heavy, you need help if native speakers have trouble understanding you. This applies to all languages learners of any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to engage in conversation with native speakers, if you have any available. Let them know that you seek to improve your language skills and to let you know when you mispronounce something. Having said that, pronunciation and accent varies widely among native speakers, even within a country.

An alternative is to watch television (e.g. BBC News) or film, or listen to the radio. There are many online broadcasters and, if you choose from the "better quality" stations rather those that employ "shock-jocks", you will hear better enunciated English - English less affected by regional accents or dialects.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! There may actually be a small chance I can find a native speaker, now that you mention it. As for some kind of media content, what am I looking for, when I'm trying to find such enunciated English? Is it a British company of the BBC caliber as a producer? Or is there, perhaps, something else?